# If God already has everything written does that mean people are destined to go to Hell regardless of choices?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Something has been affecting my my health recently and I haven’t found a single answer so I want to know if anyone knows one.

I heard that Allah has everything written down already and knows the outcome of everything. What’s the point of evil people existing or does that not contradict the idea of being just since people were created just to go to Hell and God knows?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of predestination is highly discussed, and in the end, the best thing to come to is accept that it is not possible for us to understand fully.

We believe two things: 1) Everything is known by Allah and predestined, and 2) people choose whatever actions they do and that leads to their fate in Hell or Heaven.

The difference between the two is that Allah does not force people to do anything. He simply knows what they will choose and predestined it.

On the other hand, people aren't forced to do things Allah predestined. Rather, they do what Allah predestined because they chose it, not because they were forced.

Allah is also the Most Just and Most Merciful. He doesn't punish people for something they were forced to do. This is apparent in our law: a person isn't punished for eating pork or drinking alcohol when he is starving.

So, it is clear that predestination doesn't force people to do anything. Rather, it is simply the fact that Allah had knowledge of the future beforehand, wrote it in a book, and created the future. He did not force people.

If it is too difficult for you to understand, then don't try to delve deep into it. This is a highly discussed topic and there are many books written on the concept qadr. Qadr (predestination) is the sixth pillar of faith.

Believe that Allah predestined things and people weren't forced to do them (rather they chose in free will), and you will be fine. Do not delve deeper into it if you cannot understand it.

Some people ask: How can it be a free choice when I can only do one thing?

Answer: The reason you can do one thing is because Allah knew what you would choose! It is not because Allah limited your choices in such a way that you were unable to choose what you actually wanted.

A hadith is narrated about this topic that:

> The Prophet (SAW) said: "There is not one amongst you whom a seat in
> Paradise or Hell has not been allotted and about whom it has not been
> written down whether he would be an evil person or a blessed person."
>
> Someone asked: "Allah's Messenger, should we not then depend upon our
> destiny and abandon our deeds? "
>
> Then, the Prophet said: "Acts of everyone will be facilitated in that
> which has been created for him so that whoever belongs to the company
> of the blessed will have good works made easier for him and whoever
> belongs to the unfortunate ones will have evil acts made easier for
> him."
>
> (Sahih Muslim)

The meaning of this hadith is that even when everything is predestined, we should still do acts because *we* do not know the destiny. You do not know whether you will enter Hell or Heaven. That makes all the difference. The actions you do now will decide whether you were destined for Hell or Heaven, even if from Allah's pov, it is already decided. From our pov, our actions will decide it.

Comment: If God knows what is going to happen God created everything and it’s all written down so by that logic it’s all going according to Gods plan and everyone will end up where they do as God wills so technically, if it is predestined God decided that it is going to happen if it’s not decided isn’t that like basically God didn’t choose or decide what happened and the humans did, that doesn’t make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

you have a choice for everything (free will), I think that's the main issue.

there's no such thing as an evil person in Islam. the fitrah of a human being is always good...

human is made from an image of God (Christianity perspective), Human is the best creations of God ( Islam perspective). so let's put the idea of an evil person aside

although human is his best creation doesn't mean satan or the devil cannot persuade us..

you can use a knife to slice vegetables but you can also use it as a tool to hurt others, you're the one who took the decision. so by fitrah there no such things as evil person

And no this doesn't violate or contradict his attribute of being just..please keep in mind that life itself is just a test.

for those who understood, the existence of hell isn't for punishing but rather to purify (not eternal). Eventually, we will enter paradise even the evilest person ever alive will enter paradise. this topic is quite broad actually

please have a read on conversation between God and the devil before god send us to earth

Comment: "but rather to purify (not eternal)." What do you mean hell isn't eternal ? It is said a countless amount of time that hell is eternal for the disbelievers.

Comment: for non-believers yes it is a punishment. for them, they're damned for eternity, but for believers no that's why I said: "for those who understood" .....GOD knows the devil going to tempt humans, and some of us will fail, yet the heaven door still open for the believer ..have you read the conversation between God and the devil? this will answer your question regarding the God atribute of being just ..by allowing the devil to deceive us, altering our decisions he's being fair with both devil and human..in the end of the day GOD made us as **Caliph** in the face of the earth

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @The Z has said in the other answer.

I think people ask these questions because they hear that Allah wanted people for some to live in luxury, in pain, rich or poor and wrote it in the Book. But there is a big difference between God giving rizk and God deciding what you'll do. Fortune isn't something we can control but our actions are something we can control.